# Inserting Data In Wordpress Database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert users name and email in the wordpress database which I created at the time of wordpress installation. Name of my database is "wpuser". When I try to add user in that database using following code,the code is not working and user is not get added in the database.Can anybody help me with this?

```
 include_once('/var/www/html/wp-config.php');
    include_once('/var/www/html/wp-load.php');
    if($bearer_token){
        global $wpdb;
        $name = $_POST['log'];
        $email = $_POST['log'];
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpuser";
        $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ) );

    }
```

Comment: put a die and see whether it is coming to the if condition

Comment: It is not executing " $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ) );"  this part,don't know why?. Any Solutions?

Comment: So, you have 2 databases: first is wordpress, and second is `wpuser`, right?

Comment: No. I have only one database called "wpuser".

Comment: Is it not coming inside if condition ?

Comment: It is going in "if" condition but it is not executing "$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ) );" this part which is main part.

Comment: 'wpuser' - this is your database or table name.

Comment: First of all, database and table is different things. IF you have TABLE, named `wpuser`, then why you trying to add `$wpdb->prefix` to your table name? And what is your `$wpdb->prefix` for tables? Give us RIGHT information to get right answers